# Em termos de desempenho, qual o melhor modo de declarar uma variável que será usada em várias Actions/Métodos em uma classe?

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação

Qual modo é melhor performaticamente falando?

Qual modo vocês recomendam e por que?

```
//Modo 1
MeuManager mm = new MeuManager();

JsonResponse MetodoDOIS(string urlImagem)
{
    var abc = mm.Lista();
}

JsonResponse MetodoUM(ImageUploadContent imageUpload)
{
    var abc = mm.Lista();
}

//Modo 2
JsonResponse MetodoDOIS(string urlImagem)
{
    MeuManager mm = new MeuManager();
    var abc = mm.Lista();
}

JsonResponse MetodoUM(ImageUploadContent imageUpload)
{
    MeuManager mm = new MeuManager();
    var abc = mm.Lista();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em termos de desempenho provavelmente o modo 1 é mais rápido, porque terá que instanciar apenas uma vez contra a outra forma que possivelmente será instanciado mais vezes. Aí também há fatores não determinísticos. Pode até ocorrer uma pequena diferença por ajudar encher o *cache*, pressionar o *garbage collector* por mais tempo ou com mais objetos, ou algo assim, mas nada diretamente relacionado.

Mas não é tão simples, depende de como e quanto os métodos serão chamados, quantas classes desse tipo existirão e outras coisas que nem consigo pensar agora. Performance real é algo complicado a não ser em algo muito contido.

Variáveis de instância só deveriam existir se elas fazem parte do objeto. Isso normalmente indica que você precisa ter só uma instância nesse objeto. Claro que precisa ser pragmático, pode ser que o desempenho seja realmente muito importante, mas a semântica correta é mais importante. E olhe que nem estou falando de legibilidade ou facilidade de manutenção.

Se só deve ter um gerenciador por objeto, é estranho criar um em cada método. Se deve ter mais que um, então não deveria estar no objeto.

Pode ser que nem deveria estar no método, nem na instância, deveria estar na classe (estático). Não tem contexto para saber. Essa seria ainda mais rápida porque só existiria uma instância para toda aplicação. Tem desvantagens também.

De qualquer forma a diferença de velocidade será mínima. Provavelmente tem outros lugares que haverá mais benefício, talvez nem ter essa classe `MeuManager` se for pertinente.

Comment: Valeu a resposta, não da p/ ser estático (não é uma classe do sistema, é de uma .dll 3ª), seguindo o que você falou, vou usar o modo 1, além de ser PARTE do objeto, essa instancia declarada desse modo facilita a leitura (na minha opinião), muito obrigado.